# SEO, multilanguage, session var

Tags: seo

have multilanguage site.
When the user wants to change language he must click relevant link and session var is set with the language id. Then after this session is used to get the proper content from the DB.
Default language when entering the site for the first time is english. (session var is set to english lan id)
my question is: How google robot will index this site?
Only english? what if robot will 'click' one from the language links in the begining of the indexing? will it be then set to the given language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your site will only be indexed in english.
If you wish to do multi site I'd suggest OR multi domains(.de .nl .fr. es etc...) or use multi subdomains for the different languages (nl.domain.tld, de.domain.tld, .fr.domain.tld, etc...)
Then use to cookies to redirect users tot he right domain/subdomain if they have given preference to a certain language.

That way google can index all the languages and increases your changes of being ranked for "local"/country wide search results.

Comment: ok, but if I want to use urls like de.mydomain.com I would have to create a new sub directory on my server(de, nl etc) an copy the whole site there? and do this for all languages?

Comment: No, what you can do is put in the subdirectory an index.php which loads the main loader of your site by including it, but setting the language to german, spanish or whatever.

Comment: You could even use .htaccess to load domain de.domain.tld to be basedir/index.php?lang=de&myothervarshere